# Mapview delegate function continues to run after dismissing View Controller that contains mapview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, delegates, mapbox

I'm using mapbox and firebase. 
I have a delegate function that updates the user's coordinates(inside of the firebase database) when the user's location changes.
To the best of my knowledge, it functions as it should when signed into the app. The mapviews delegate is the view controller (`self.mapView.delegate = self`)

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool){
            let latitude = mapView.userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
            let longitude = mapView.userLocation?.coordinate.longitude
          Database.database().reference().child(pathToCoord).updateChildValues(["latitude":latitude, "longitude":longitude], withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil { print(err!); return }
        }
```

When I sign out of the app, I would like to stop updating the user location.
Ideally I would just like the View Controller with the map to go away completely and for everything on it to stop running.
I've written this sign out function that try several different methods of making sure that the location is no longer updated.

```
func signOut(){

    for id in Auth.auth().currentUser?.providerData{
        if id.providerID == "facebook.com"{
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        }
    }
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    }catch let logoutError {
        print(logoutError)
    }


    self.mapView.delegate = nil
    if let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as? SignInViewController{
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Sometimes when I'm logged out though, I continuously get the error below in my console. The most logical solution I can think of for why this is happening is that the View Controller is still running. I don't know how to make it stop.

```
[Firebase/Database] updateChildValues: at `path/to/coord` failed: permission_denied
Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied}
```

---

Edit

So it looks like the problem was probably that I had this in my SignInViewController

```
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
               if let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController{
        vc.uid = uid
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc

    }
    }
```

And then the delegate would run once for each uid, as if two of the view controllers were running at the same time. When I signed out, I'm guessing the other one didn't sign out and kept running for the other user id.

This is off topic to my original question but I'd like to know what the proper way to check if a user is already signed in, and then sign them in is. Because clearly my method didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try dismiss with Completion Handler block like below.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    if let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as? SignInViewController{
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc

   }
})
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work because the view i'm on is the root view controller, I feel like I can't dismiss it because theres nothing under it.

Comment: sorry for late i was on vacation, Anyhow u resolved the problem?